# Typescript keep a copy of object's initial state

Tags: angular, typescript

im working on angular2 typescript project ,I just want to reset the object's key to '' after calling save( ) function  , example is below

```
export class Events{
    event:any={ name : '', date : '',.........};
    eventOriginal=this.event;

    save(){

      //save(this.event)

      //after save, reset value to initial state

      this.event=this.eventOriginal;

    }

  }
```

but in console.log(this.event) the value is not cleared, both objects are same. i tried to assign value from constructor too,
so, what is the proper way to reset keys of object in typescript ?

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an object to another you are only assigning the reference.

## Quick fix

Clone the object using spread

```
export class Events{
    event={ name : '', date : '',.........};
    eventOriginal= {...this.event};
```

Comment: Does the OP code even work? `class Events { eventOriginal = this.event }` -> `this.event === window.event`?

Comment: {...this.event}; seems it does not support in my typescript version

Answer (score 1):

The step `eventOriginal=this.event;` will just assign the ***reference*** in javascript.

The `Object.assign()` method should be used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties. like

```
eventOriginal = Object.assign({}, this.event);
```

and then later

```
this.event= Object.assign({}, this.eventOriginal);
```